# Disable online accounts icon

Tags: online-accounts

How can I prevent the online accounts icon from showing in the launcher?

After installing 13.04 and logging in to Gmail in Firefox, I was asked if I wanted to add Gmail to online accounts.  I clicked 'yes' and then changed my mind before entering my password.  Now whenever I log in to Gmail in Firefox, an online accounts icon shows up in the launcher.  If I right click and choose 'quit' then the Gmail tab in Firefox closes.  How can I remove this icon permanently, or else disable online accounts entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use unity tweak tool, you can download it from Ubuntu software center after downloading it go to Web Apps tab.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUaEc.png